# How to add app from SharePoint store?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, app

This is only on SharePoint online.
I am trying to add app from the SharePoint store online but when I request the app I get a message ‘ Your tenant administrator has to approve this app’. (not sure who is the tenant administrator?) I am SP Admin
But when I check app catalog and change the status to approve I still can’t find the app to add it to the site. What I am missing any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you click "ADD IT" in SharePoint store after approving it in app catalog site? If "Good news - you already have this on your site." appears on the app purchasing page?

[image]

Comment: I did try but its still grayed out.